# Shrink a big array to one that only contains one String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I collect some users from my database with JSON. I prefer to have an array that contains all information about the user.

But for the rest of the application I only need to have an array with the prenames of the users as Strings.

`db_users` is the array with the complete user information. `users` only contains the prename.

```
var db_users = [];
var users = [];
var counter = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, user) {
            db_users.push({
                workerid: user.workerid,
                prename: user.prename,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                avatar: user.avatar,
                lineup: user.lineup,
                languages: user.languages,
                partnerid: user.partnerid,
                code: user.code,
                partnerName: user.partnerName,
                street: user.street,
                zip: user.zipCode,
                city: user.city,
                email: user.email,
                phone: user.phone,
                slogan: user.slogan
            });

            users[counter] = user.prename;
            counter++;
        });
    }
});
```

What do I have to do to use `db_users` the same way as I use `users`? Is there something like
`[db_users prename];` that will create an array with only the prenames as Strings?

This is how it should be used later on:

```
//users: ['Laura', 'Sarah', 'Alice'],
users: users,
```

Comment: It looks like you are already creating your `users` array. So what's the problem?

Comment: I only want to have the `db_users` array, the `users` array is just there to show you how I will use it in the end.

Comment: `for (var n = 0; n < db_users.length; n++) {db_users[n] = db_users[n].prename;}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform an array into another array. However, I think the way you have it in your question is actually better. Calling `.map` will involve iterating through the whole array again. It's much better to just build it when you first iterate through the array and keep it cached.

If all you want to do is access the `prename` property, then @Wolf has your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a separate array for this. You have to use the following code

```
db_users[index].prename; // This will give you the name
```

index is the index in the array....